# stop function if window.width less than pixels

Tags: javascript, jquery

i work with this plugin
[3d-gallery-with-css3-and-jquery](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/06/3d-gallery-with-css3-and-jquery) in my website.

i want to stop the slider from working, if the screen is less than 900 px.

i tried many ways but none of them work for me.

any suggestions?

```
if($(window).width() > 900) {
    $(function() {
        $('#dg-container').gallery();
    });
}

$(window).resize(function() {
    if($(window).width() < 900) {
        // how to stop the .gallery();
    }
});
```

in the slider i have found this code.

```
destroy : function() {
    this.$navPrev.off('.gallery');
    this.$navNext.off('.gallery');
    this.$wrapper.off('.gallery');
}
```

but the question is how to use this function?

Comment: what gallery plugin are you using? go through its docs and try to locate a `destroy` or similar method.

Comment: Hi @Ejay, this plugin: http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/02/06/3d-gallery-with-css3-and-jquery/

Comment: Try changing `<` to `<=`.

Comment: @slime the problem is not the if < or <=. the problem is how to stop the function.

Comment: try `$('#dg-container').data('gallery').destroy();` but it doesn't do much. You'll have to make layout changes yourself if that's what you're after

Comment: the destroy will only remove the on events. He needs to set the this.options.autoplay to false to get it to stop. the plugin is poorly written for stopping and starting and needs a new function on its prototype to kill the boolean as well as the timer.

Comment: It would be awesome if you cold format that _horror_. People will appreciate that you take 10 extra seconds to produce a greater quality question and are going to be _much_ more likely to answer.

Comment: BTW. This plug-in has a very bad performance, maybe reconsider using it in your development.

Comment: @user2413244, If you're able to ignore IE9 you could use the [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia) api.

Answer (score 0):

This gallery has a really limited API.  If it was me, I'd remove the gallery instance altogether in your UI layer (simply .remove() the div and contents) and then replace it with your desired other content, whether that's a picture or something else.